# ios block issue - when return takes action

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I am not sure about blocks and I can't get my mind clear about a point

I have a block, for instance using a famous XML parsor (Rapture XML)

```
[data iterate:@"node" usingBlock: ^(RXMLElement *leaf) {

NSLog (@"Data");

}

NSLog (@"End of parse");
```

When does the end of parse is called ? When I finished all iterations (like it seems) or their is a "question of time" depending on duration of the loop ?

for instance an animation return after call BUT before execution, rapture seem to return after execution

thanks

greg

Answer (score 0):

This is procedural, think of the block as a function being called to do the work on each element, it's just written inline.

In respect to animations, if: `[data iterate:@"node" usingBlock: ^(RXMLElement *leaf){ }];` is doing alot of work on the main thread, it will block the main thread.